# Having trouble with my Class Method and getting it to work in my new View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a project app with a table containing about 100 projects `<% @projects.each do |project| %>`
In my main view `index.html.erb` I list all of the projects. In my class model I wrote 2 methods to let me know if the projects are late? or duesoon? `def late?` and `def duesoon` 
`if (actual_date.present && actual_date < Date.today) then true` Anyway, that is some of the logic. I added some background-color styles to show Red for late and yellow for duesoon. 
My **issue** is I have created a 2nd View page where I only want to display the projects that are Late or DueSoon. This should be fairly easy but I have been racking my brain trying to get this working properly. I like this approach:

```
class Project               
def self.projectLate
where(late: true)
end
end
```

then adding something like this to the view:

`<% @projects.projectLate.each do |project| %>`

I am quite new to rails so appreciate the help trying to get this piece setup. Thanks.

***Edited***

So I got it to work, although I realize it is probably not the best method.

In my controller I had created `def delinquent` for my 2nd view page. 
Then I added the following code:

```
@projects_temp = Project.order(sort_column + "" + sort_direction)
@projects = []
@projects_temp.each do |project|
 if project.late?
 @projects.push project
```

I realize its oldschool but it worked. I will still look into scope for future queries.
Thanks for those who helped.

Comment: Is your class method `projectLate` or `delinquent`?  Your model shows `projectdLate` but your view is using `delinquent`.

Comment: There's no delinquent in the snippet shared

Comment: Sorry, just saw that. Edited it. My real new page is called the Delinquent page. Was using projectLate as an example.

Answer (score 1):

You should seriously consider not using a class method like that and instead using a scope. Second thing, you should change your duesoon method to not use and if...then block. Here's a couple suggestions for your code:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :late, lambda { :conditions => ['actual_date IS NOT NULL AND actual_date < ?', Date.today] }
end
```

And then in the controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @projects = Projects.all
  end
end
```

And then in the view:

```
<% @projects.late.each do |project| %>
  <%= "Late project #{project}" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I will try using Scope. See if that works for me. Thanks

Comment: my `def Late` method also contains a If Then block. So can I do something like `scope :duesoon, lambda { :conditions **"duesoon logic"**}` right under `scope :late` and combine them. Since I want to return late and duesoon projects....

Comment: You can have as many scopes as you want. I would create two scopes if you wanted to do that. One for duesoon, and one for duesoon or late. The reason is, duesoon would be fine as a query, but duesoon or late would be array addition, which is expensive. If you instead wrote one query, it would be much faster.

Comment: Great. 1 more thing, the condition is actual pretty long. For example there are 4 different ways a project can be late. That is why I was using If, elsIF, elsIF,.... I will look more into scope, but am assuming the :conditions => take If statements?

Comment: The `:conditions =>` is a sql query. It's an array, and it replaces any instance of `?` with the value given. So for instance, `['value > ? AND value < ? AND value2 != ?', 5, 10, 7]`. In this case, it's easiest to just `rails db` and make sure your query is correct, and then simply plug it into the conditions array.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<% @projects.delinquent.each do |project| %>
  <%= project if (project.late? || project.duesoon?) %>
<% end %>
```

and let me know if you get any error.

Comment: I like this process. Correction though - In my view I have `<% @projects.each do |project| %>` In my controller I added a `def delinquent` for the 2nd view page, but all I did was mimic `def index` Then in the model is where I attempted to do the `def self.projectLate
where(late: true)
end
end`

Comment: Then add `<% @projects.projectsLate.each do |project| %>' to the view.

Comment: step 1 could be to try to print out all the projects: <%= project %>.  See what comes back.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there!

Just change the

```
@projects.delinquent
```

into

```
@projects.projectLate.delinquent
```

and you're done!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - In my view I have `<% @projects.each do |project| %>` In my controller I added a `def delinquent` for the 2nd view page, but all I did was mimic `def index` Then in the model is where I attempted to do the `def self.projectLate where(late: true) end end` then add  `<% @projects.projectsLate.each do |project| %>` to my new view